# Option to display formatted C program in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, css, c

What are the option that I can use to display formatted C Program in iOS. What I can think of right now is
1. Make a HTML file with code in it, and find some CSS to display in web view. **Not** a good option as I have to manually handle formatting.
2. Use some kind of parser to convert it in `NSAttributedString` and then display it in UITextView.

If correct option is **one** , pointer to any such CSS or java script would be great help, or if option is **two** is there any such parser available.

**Or** is there any other option to achieve same.

Comment: Not sure if prettifier will do what you need, it formats code but not sure if it formats objective C

Comment: There's an app called [Kodiak for PHP](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/kodiak-for-php/id542685332?mt=8) on the iTunes store which does similar thing (for PHP code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookd in [pretty print](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html) and looks like it can format cpp see the following example:
You could try to paste your code in here and have it formatted (if you don't need it done dynamically). Then use Firefox with firebug plugin to right click the element, go to the root and copy the thml. Copy the css files as well (under the CSS tab you can find them)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<title>Example</title>
</head>
 <body>
   <pre class="prettyprint lang-cpp">
int
foo(int k)
{
        if (k < 1 || k > 2) {
                printf("out of range\n");
                printf("this function requires a value of 1 or 2\n");
        } else {
                printf("Switching\n");
                switch (k) {
                case 1:
                        printf("1\n");
                        break;
                case 2:
                        printf("2\n");
                        break;
                }
        }
}
   </pre>


 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was looking for some more powerful tool, as I have to formate lots of code, all in different file :(.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no API available for do this.

**My suggestion:**

Convert your code to html and load it in `UIWebView`. I know there is a lot of difficulties behind this.

You can use [codeformatter](http://codeformatter.blogspot.in/2009/06/about-code-formatter.html) for converting your code to html. Hence there is no api's available this is one solution.

I had wrote an open-source library for doing this.
Please check [MMP_CodeViewer](https://github.com/Midhun-MP/MMP_CodeViewer)

Comment: @AmitSingh: Please check [MMP_CodeViewer](https://github.com/Midhun-MP/MMP_CodeViewer)

Answer (score 0):

iOS port of Vim editor is available [here](https://github.com/applidium/Vim). Not sure if you are looking for code editing as well.